# why image with onclick property get clicked on pressing enter first time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a logon page for an application which asks for user id and password and then use following code for submitting it after validation.

```
<input Type="image" ID="btnMsgOk" src='images\Button\Normal\Ok.gif' onclick="release();return true;" onkeydown="escapeKey();" onmousemove="buttonMouseOver('btnMsgOk')" onmouseout="buttonMouseOut('btnMsgOk')" />
```

Once the page is loaded and 1st time I press enter key this ok get clicked but if page is not relaoded and enter key is pressed again it is not getting clicked , there is no `onkeypress` event in this page.
In the same way I have different jsp pages which use images and add  `onclick` event to it to call different function even for submitting the form.
In this pages even though functionality is defined for `onkeypress` event which defines the function key to press the image responsible for submitting the form, but when the jsp page is loaded and first time enter key is pressed it doesn't fires the function which is defined by `onkeypress` event but it fires the function defined by the 1st image on page which has `onclick` functionality and second time it behaves in the way it should i.e firing the function defined by `onkeypress` event and hence clicking the right button.

Comment: keydown event escapeKey() will fire first before onclick

Comment: Can you provide the JS code here?

Comment: js code for function releated to  onclick or on oneydown event?

Answer (score 0):

Disable it explicitly by below code::

```
   function stopRKey(evt) { 
      var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
      var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
      if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
    } 

    document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
```